# cross site scripting using script tag ,change src of a script tag, can we use id for script tag

Tags: javascript, xss

```
<body>
<!-- some html code -->

<script src='some.js'></script>

<!-- some html code -->

</body>
```

The script some.js loads a form.
when i press update in that form i do not submit the form instead i form a query string and want to send it as
some.js?key=value

Now i need to change the src of the script tag.

If we change the src will it work by again requesting a new content?
Can we use ID for script tag and if so will it be supported by all browsers?

when the new content is received i will clear the old content displayed by this script.
i think it is better to have a div and put all the contents inside that div.
i am rewriting script.js to script.php in my htaccess just show the users that it is just a javascript access or no problem for me if i give a .php.

The above is the basic requirement.

What we need is just to use a script tag which will fetch content from another site and should update here.

you can give suggestions to use this in a standard way which will included updating the content from the x site.

so this is what people tell as cross site scripting, on demand javascript and please add more terminologies if any so that i will update myself.

any kind of response will do good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to W3C (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) 'script' tag doesn't support any standard attributes (which includes 'id'), however it will work in most browsers. Instead of replacing 'script' tag 'src' attribute I would suggest removing the tag and adding new one - that’s more reliable. I would strongly suggest reading about JSONP and Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) - those are standards which should help you achieve what you want.

Comment: The W3C is an organization that publishes specifications relating to the web. W3Schools is an organization that publishes poor quality tutorials but is good at SEO. They are **not** the same organization. The script element does support an id attribute in some versions of HTML.

Comment: I have never wrote they are the same organization, although I admit I have posted wrong link (edited now). The rest stays true.

Comment: what if i had many script tags and i may not know where it exactly positioned? shall i wrap that script tag into a div with an id like <div id='jscriptid'><script></script></div> so that we can manipulate the script tag inside the div...

Answer (score 2):

As @tpeczek mentioned, to change the script src attribute is not enough, some browsers will not reload the script.
Use the following to replace the tag:

```
var oldScript = document.getElementById('someID');
var script = document.createElement("script");        
script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");                
script.setAttribute("id","someID");
script.setAttribute("src",url);

if (oldScript == null) {               
    document.body.appendChild(script);
} else {
    document.body.replaceChild(script, oldScript);
}
```

Comment: People say that id will not work. Except that your code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

couldnt you go the old fashioned way and walk through all script elements and check the src to find some.js?

Comment: it will work but a more tedious way comparing to the other replies

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**
As a [global attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html), `id` appears to be supported for [script](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html) tags in HTML5.