# Javascript: update a src with dynamic info

Tags: javascript, dynamic, document.write

I am trying to dynamically change the src of a  tag. It pulls in the src to the tag just fine, but it doesn't run the javascript inside of the "example.js"

My.html

```
<script src='' id="s1"></script>

    <script language="javascript">
         function changeSrc()
         {
         s1.src = "example.js";
         };
         changeSrc();
    </script>
```

example.js

```
document.write('<a href="www.mywebsite.com"><img src="somecoolimage.gif" alt="myweb"/></a>');
```

Example.js isn't writing the above info.

Comment: Found the solution here: [link1](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=355210#p355210), [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966756/cross-site-scripting-using-script-tag-change-src-of-a-script-tag-can-we-use-id) ,just create a new `script` tag and it should update ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the `src` of a `script` block dynamically (it's not consistent across different browsers), add a new `script` block instead:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'example.js';
document.getElementById('some_div_id').appendChild(script);
```

Comment: I actually need to append the script inside the body of the html. Perhaps inside a <div>.

Comment: @DanRivers: Ok, instead of `document.head` use `document.getElementById('your_div_id').appendChild(script)`.

Comment: Strange. it actually writes out the <script> and the src just fine, but fails to execute the javascript within the example.js.